# Не работает Swagger в браузере (OpenApi), микросервис SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

Коллеги нужна ваша помощь, обычный Rest микросервис SpringBoot, хочу сделать документацию, подключил зависимость:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
 <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

В большинстве "мануалов", расположенных в Интернете сказано, что этого достаточно, чтобы после запуска микросервиса и перехода по адресу:
`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`
в браузере отобразилась стандартная форма Swagger, с методами RestController'в.

Моя проблема в том, что при переходе по указанному адресу, осуществляется redirect на страницу:
`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`
и отображается пустая страница.

В консоли приложения (использую Idea) вижу следующее сообщение:

```
GET "/swagger-ui.html", parameters={}
Mapped to org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc#redirectToUi(HttpServletRequest)
Using 'application/json', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
Nothing to write: null body
Completed 302 FOUND
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я неправильно делаю, и как можно исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Одно из решений использовать спринг до версии 2.6.х
Я сам постоянно использую сваггер и уже думал что головой поехал так как брал зависимости и бины с настройками из рабочих проектов которые делал сам. Но вылетала эта ошибка))) на днях нашёл такое решение. Идея по умолчанию создаёт на версии 2.6.8 сегодня а тут не работает

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас Spring-boot 3+, то надо использовать Swagger 2+ (artifactId:
springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui)